# FireBug debugging

Tags: debugging, firefox, firebug

Hello i'm debugging in Firebug following JS script:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var val = 8;

        function funMul(value) { //1.
            var val = 7;
            val = val*value;
            return val;
            }

        var result = funMul(val);
        document.write('<b>funMul: </b>' + result);
    </script>
</body>
```

I have a breakpoint defined on the (1.) line. But "Step Into" doesn't seem to work. It doesn't step into funMul function. It behaves just like "Step Over" just leave out & termine the script.

So how to make it to really jump into function body?

ps.
Is it possible to debug the code ("Step Into") of DOM methods like document.write or events like onLoad?

Answer (score 0):

To step into the function, you need to put the debugger on line 11 (var result = funMul(val);), as this is where the function is called.

Or you put a breakpoint directly in the function itself, line 6 (var val = 7;)